# Integral of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, definition

The logarithm is defined as:
$$
\ln x = \int_1^x \frac1{t} dt
$$
Hence I am often told that for indefinite integrals, since $\frac1{x}$ is defined over $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ (various sources seem to disagree about this), one should write:
$$
\int \frac1{x}dx = \ln |x|+C
$$
How is this justified?

(PS I think I might be duplicating someone else, if I am please link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One writes $\displaystyle \int \frac1x dx=\ln|x|$, because you should take into account cases where $x<0$.

In the definition $\displaystyle \ln x = \int_1^x \frac1{t} dt$, only the values for $x>0$ are taken into account.

Comment: Would this in any way contradict logarithm identities involving complex numbers?

Comment: @JamesHarrison see Sherlock Holmes' answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is said that $\int \frac{1}{x}$d$x=\ln |x| +c$ because we must account for when $x<0$ as well as when $x>0$. I believe the justification is derived from Euler's identity:

$e^{i \pi}+1=0 \implies e^{i \pi}= -1 \implies i\pi=\ln(-1)$

When $x<0$, then we have the indefinite integral giving $\ln (-x)+c_1=\ln (x)+ c +i\pi=\ln (x) +c_2$

So they differ by $i\pi$.